# Can't generate facebook access token

Tags: python

I need to generate the Facebook access token for a project.
Code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'
payload = {
'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
'client_id': 'clientid',
'client_secret': 'secret'
}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
print (response.json()['access_token'])
```

What I'm getting as output is my id|type, after research I found that it is due to the 'client_credential' request. I need to generate access tokens for a project (I want to use them to find likes etc). Any help would be appreciated, it's my first time attempting a project like this.

Answer (score 0):

use [facebook-sdk.][1]

```
import facebook

    app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
    
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI()
    
    # exactly what you're after ;-)
    access_token = graph.get_app_access_token(app_id, app_secret)
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Your code generates the same output as mine (i.e. id|type ), what I want to generate is the access token that u can get from Facebook GraphAPI.

Comment: Looks like you were going to add a like to the Facebook SDK - did you forget to?